# How to replace IP address with machine name

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, iis, windows-server-2003

My web service is hosted on Windows server 2003 IIS and working fine with IP address like below:

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:42580/Service.svc

When I'm replacing the IP address with server name, its showing error:

```
 This error (HTTP 400 Bad Request) means that Internet Explorer was able to   connect to the web server, but the webpage could not be found because of a problem with the address.

 For more information about HTTP errors, see Help.
```

I tried adding Ip address with server name in the "host" file. But, this is not working as well. 
Could any one please help, how to correct this? or anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

The site in IIS needs to be configured to recognise and route the host name to the appropriate site instance (the one currently running under the IP address).

Select the site properties, edit the *bindings* and add the host name to the corresponding input box.

Comment: I'm using IIS 6.0. In this I tried, site properties - > Web site -> IP Address - > Advanced then "Host header value" to a appropriate name. But this is not working. I'm getting error "This error (HTTP 400 Bad Request) means that this program was able to connect to the web server, but the webpage could not be found because of a problem with the address." In my application web.config, I have "base address" as "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:42580/Service.svc" .Do I need to change something in config file also?

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the DNS cache of the PC, in CMD run: ipconfig /flushdns

also make sure your browser like Firefox is not caching the DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS if it is configured properly or not, and try flushing it and registering again

In the Command prompt try following commands in sequence and try again.

ipconfig /flushdns

ipconfig /registerdns